# Setting numberFormat for a range throws InvalidArgument error

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I have the following snippet that I wrote on ScriptLab, and I'm running this snippet on a sample file:

```
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    var r = sheet.getUsedRange().getRow(14) 
    r.load('values, numberFormat')
    await context.sync()

    console.log(r.values) //94
    console.log(r.numberFormat)
    var newvals = [new Array(r.values[0].length).fill('0')]
    var newformats = [new Array(r.values[0].length).fill('General')]

    console.log(newvals)
    console.log(newformats)

    r.values = newvals
    r.numberFormat = newformats

    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

All it does is replace row 14 (which has 94 cells) with zeroes in every cell, and set the numberFormat for every cell to 'General'.

However, when I run this snippet, I get the following error:

```
n {name: "RichApi.Error", code: "InvalidArgument", traceMessages: Array[0], innerError: null, debugInfo: Object…}
 name: "RichApi.Error"

 code: "InvalidArgument"

 traceMessages: Array[0]

 innerError: null

▶debugInfo: Object
 code: "InvalidArgument"

 message: "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."

 toString: function toString()

 errorLocation: "Range.numberFormat"

 statement: "v.numberFormat = ...;"

▶surroundingStatements: Array[5]
 0: "var v = context.workbook._getObjectByReferenceId("R!{67391A8A-2E99-4E0F-A4E9-D0828C198E04}!{9F93B642-E246-468F-935E-A7A870CC754F}");"

 1: "v.values = ...;"

 2: "// >>>>>"

 3: "v.numberFormat = ...;"

 4: "// <<<<<"

▶fullStatements: Array[1]

 httpStatusCode: 400
```

This points to the numberFormat array being unacceptable for some reason, but I can't figure out why. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems my error message is different from what you pasted. what else in the worksheet?
n {name: "RichApi.Error", code: "InvalidArgument", traceMessages: Array[0], innerError: null, debugInfo: Object…}
 name: "RichApi.Error"

 code: "InvalidArgument"

 traceMessages: Array[0]

 innerError: null

▶debugInfo: Object
 code: "InvalidArgument"

 message: "Parameter out of range"

 toString: function ()

 errorLocation: "Range.getRow"

 statement: "var row = usedRange.getRow(...);"
▶fullStatements: Array[1]

 httpStatusCode: 400

 data: undefined

Comment: I tried it with a fresh file. Added some information to the first few cells of the first row and changed the code to `getRow(0)`. This gave me the error I mentioned.

Comment: Just had another try, it runs successfully on my side, no error shown at all, any more tips for repro this bug?

Comment: @RaymondLu The values are applied but the error is still thrown in ScriptLab and on the application I'm working on... My version of Excel is 2009 build 13231.20262 click-to-run, Windows 10 10.0.19041.

Comment: @RaymondLu Some colleagues are able to run the addin without errors, and they're on the same OS and Excel versions. Is it possible that we're pulling different versions of the CDN?

Comment: Correction: My colleagues who are able to run the addin are on OS version 10.0.18363 Build 18363. Seems to be the only difference.

Comment: this behavior described as well here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1561