# How to define a specific version of Office.JS in an addin

Tags: webpack, office-js, office-addins

I developed an Excel add-in that's been in use internally for about a year. Recently the add-in stopped working even though no changes were made to the code. I assume this is related to the new version of the API (1.12), which must have changed something that I was using.

On the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn) I can only find explanations on how to use the CDN, which provides the latest version. How can I determine the exact version I want to use?

---

### EDIT

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js#using-the-npm-package), I'm trying to use Webpack to copy all office.js files from `node_modules` to the dist directory. I can see that Webpack finds the files, due to the following output:

```
...
../../../../../../../dist/office/ta-in/outlook_strings.debug.js   15.3 KiB
 [emitted]
...
```

But the files do not appear on the `dist` directory. Below is the relevant export from my `webpack.config.js`:

```
frontConf = {
  entry: [ './src/js/index.js' ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.html', '.js']
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
        // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            //options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
       test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
       use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from:'node_modules/@microsoft/office-js/dist', 
        to:'/dist/office'}
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/html/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
      excludeChunks: [ 'server' ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on how to configure Webpack for this?

Comment: Would you please share a bit more information about the issue, our principle is not to bring the breaking change, so I would like to learn more about the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your attention Raymond. The issue I'm facing is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279227/setting-numberformat-for-a-range-throws-invalidargument-error